# What's wrong with my LINQ-query?

Tags: silverlight, linq, join

It's on WP7 emulator.
I try to execute next LINQ-query:

```
from person p in logOnDB
join logonPerson lp in logOnDB on p.id equals lp.personID
join logonData ld in logOnDB on lp.id equals ld.logonID
where ld.password == passingPassword
select p;
```

But it falls with the following error:

> System.MethodAccessException was unhandled by user code

What's wrong with that? How should I make it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is a problem when you're using anonymous types.

Without more info on what logOnDB is returning it's hard to say if this is your problem. Also, can you maybe post the entire stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Ок, logOnDB it's a SiaqodbOffline object.

Comment: at Sqo.SqoQueryExtensions.Join[TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult](ISqoQuery`1 outer, IEnumerable`1 inner, Expression`1 outerKeySelector, Expression`1 innerKeySelector, Expression`1 resultSelector)

Comment: I guess that, but what should I do?

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with the siaqodb project. What it looks like to me is that it's trying to do reflection inside of  it's LINQ provider implementation and blowing up with a MethodAccessException which is because it doesn't have the rights to reflect over the types being used. I don't know enough about the product to offer much more advice than this. Perhaps you should contact the developers via their forum. There's one post on MethodAccessException here[1], but that mentions anonymous types too. [1] http://forum.siaqodb.com/index.php?topic=71.msg190#msg190

Comment: Yeah, I saw that you added on to that. If you don't get any assistance you might want to start your own post because I don't think it's the exact same problem as the original post. Good luck!